# Google Recaptcha v2 POST request to Google API (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify) getting blocked by Azure WAF, any solutions?

Tags: recaptcha

I am using Google Recaptcha v2 I'm not a Robot checkbox,

After submitting a form with the checkbox, we are verifying user response by sending POST request to Google Verify API, according to https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api_request.

Everything is working as expected, but the problem arise when we are enabling Azure WAF in between the app and Google API. The POST request containing the response sometimes got blocked by following rules:

942430 Restricted SQL Character Anomaly Detection (args): # of special characters exceeded (12)
942440 SQL Comment Sequence Detected.

Note: Azure WAF is using ruleset OWASP 3.2

We can create exclusion rule to the violated rules for ARGS:response and recaptcha will work as expected, but if possible we prefer to not create the exclusion rule if possible.

Is there any workaround to avoid this Azure WAF Rule triggered? So that I don't have to create exclusion on the triggered Azure WAF Rules.

Will it be possible for Google to amend the format of Recaptcha response as not to trigger Azure WAF?